# Azure remote desktop not working

Tags: azure

I'm trying to connect to the remote desktop but i'm getting following errors. I went to the azure portal and my rdp port is open i.e. 3389 as it's showing up in the dashboard.

Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1) Remote access to the server is not enabled 2) The remote computer is turned off 3) The remote computer is not available on the network

Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

I actually created twice but still no luck.

Comment: Please indicate if this is a Windows Azure Machine or a Cloud Service deployment. If it is a Virtual Machine did you change the IP to static (because you shouldn't)? Were you ever able to remote to this machine?  Finally, I'm assuming the portal indicated that the machine was running and not cycling or still booting, correct?

Comment: It's a azure cloud service and service is running, i even recreated the rdp but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same scenario was happen with me as well. For that i upload the certificate to the windows azure portal. After that i was able to connect to the windows azure cloud service successfully.

Comment: While doing "hit & triak" i also did the same thing, created new certificate for remote desktop and then uploaded it and then redeployed the solution. It's just a workaround but not solution, never understood why it happens all of a sudden.